# List does not exist error when adding a webPart SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts, sharepoint-list

I want to add a web part in my site collection home page containing a list that is created in on of the subsites... i looked in google for that and it looked like a simple task to do.

Almost all blogs describes the same steps which are :

1- Open the list in SPD

2- Edit the desired View

3- in webPart section in the ribbon save to file click

4- import the .webPart file

And this should be working, however every time i get the "List does not exist it might have been deleted by another user ..." error

I tried doing this from multiple subsites levels and different sites, it seems like i cannot add a webPart conataining a list in lower level site

Ps: when i add the webPart in the site home page (the site where the list is created) it works and the list is displayed...

Am i missing something?

(I am using SharePoint 2013 on permises)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same error for a 3 days. In my site I had web part with list from other site. When I removed this web part suddenly I was able to add webpart with my list from current site. I dont know what was the reason for that behaviour but it works.